# Is Python Memory management different in different IDEs?

Tags: python, memory-management, jupyter-notebook, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I ran the below code in Jupyter notebook, spyder and pycharm

```
a = 10000
b = 10000
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

The result in Jupyter notebook is the output has different memory addresses, but in spyder and pycharm they are both same.

Could someone explain why this is so? And does memory management differs for IDEs?!

Comment: Jupyter uses an [IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/execution.html) kernel to process, compile and execute 'block-wise' (this is technically not completely correct) parts inside a function. This is different from running a script with the `python` interpreter.